# XMM to General Register

Tags: assembly, sse

1. Is it possible to move **directly** `xmm` register to general purpose register?
2. Is it possible to `cmove` `xmm`
3. Is there something like conditional add?

Comment: Consult the instruction set reference. TL;DR: 1) yes 2) no 3) no but you can mask and add

Comment: 1) How to do it?, 3) What do you mean exactly?

Comment: 1) consult the reference? `movd`/`movq`  3) you can make a mask with all 1 or 0 bits, bitwise `AND` that with the addend so you get it unchanged or zeroed.